# Change imageView position in runtime

Tags: android, image

I try to change position of imageView in runtime. ImageView is in the framelayout and my main layout is relative layout.

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1); 
image.setY(100); 
image.setX(100);
```

This code works only onCreate method. I want to send image object to another class and use in some functions. When i try to do this, nothing happens. It gives no error and doesn't change position of the image

Xml for frame layout:

```
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/im1"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:background="@drawable/image"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: methed name setRotation(90) that work

Comment: I don't want rotate. I want change coordinates. I also tried this function and it also does nothing.

Comment: Could you post the function in the other class that you are trying to pass into? Where are you calling this function form, onCreate?

Comment: I call another class's function in onCreate and pass it. model.setVariables(image,...)"

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1); 
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = image.getLayoutParams();

params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) //left, top, right, bottom
image.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I think it is because you're passing the `ImageView` somewhere. You could try to keep the `ImageView` where it is (in the activity), and create a method in your Activity that handles movement of a certain Image. Not sure if that fits in your situation though.

Comment: I can create a function in activity class and call it from other class. I tried this but it gives null pointer exception. I can't use ImageView in function, i think.

Answer (score 0):

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1); 
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = image.getLayoutParams();

params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) //left, top, right, bottom
image.requestLayout(); // Or you can call to set layout params like James did
```

Comment: Calling `requestLayout()` is not needed as `setLayoutParams()` already does this. See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/view/View.java?av=f#10552).

Comment: @James Cool! Learned some thing new today.